# AsyncLocal with ASP.NET Core Controller/ServiceProviderScope

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

It seems like the execution context is not kept until `Dispose` is called on elements resolved in the controller scope. This is probably due to the fact that asp.net core has to jump between native and managed code and resets the execution context at each jump. Seems like the correct context is not restored any more before the scope is disposed.

The following demonstrates the issue - simply put this in the default asp.net core sample project and register `TestRepo` as a transient dependency.

When calling `GET api/values/` we set the value for the current task to 5 in a static AsyncLocal at the start of the call. That value flows as expected through awaits without any problem. But when the controller and its dependencies are disposed after the call the AsyncLocal context is already reset.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly TestRepo _testRepo;

    public ValuesController(TestRepo testRepo) => _testRepo = testRepo;

    [HttpGet()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        _testRepo.SetValue(5);
        await Task.Delay(100);
        var val = _testRepo.GetValue(); // val here has correctly 5.
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class TestRepo : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<int?> _asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<int?>();

    public int? GetValue() => _asyncLocal.Value;

    public void SetValue(int x) => _asyncLocal.Value = x;

    public void Foo() => SetValue(5);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (GetValue() == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(); //GetValue() should be 5 here :(
        }
    }
}
```

Is this intentional? And if yes is there any workaround around this problem?

Comment: Binding a static on a transient-scoped injection makes my brain hurt. What are you trying to do exactly? Statics are pretty much always the wrong approach with a web application, especially now in the world of ASP.NET Core, where *everything* is now dependency injected.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Sure go ahead, remove the static and make the `TestRepo` class a singleton during registration. I don't see why this is relevant for the issue at hand?

Comment: It's relevant, because you're mixing statics and dependency injection, which is asking for trouble in the first place. Trying to figure out why a particular thing is not working is moot, when it's the wrong approach to start.

Comment: @Chris There are some valid if pretty rare scenarios where you need to store context per API request and can't easily inject a scoped dependency, because you need to reset the state (say you need multiple scoped transactions during a single API call). And hey I just gave you a trivial transformation to remove the static if that's what's bothering you.

Comment: And since presumably the next argument is going to be "But I don't need AsyncLocal so you shouldn't either!" I'll just point out that yes, yes you do need `AsyncLocal` - at least assuming you're not using your own private asp.net core branch. Hell the one in ActionContextAccessor is even static - horrible really.

Comment: I disagree with @ChrisPratt on this one. There is nothing wrong with using a static `AsyncLocal<T>`, as long as this value is encapsulated *inside* the Composition Root that is.

Comment: @Steven Yeah AsyncLocal is simply a very special class where the naive "oh never use static!" simply doesn't make sense. The whole point of it is to store global state - so sure you can avoid making it static and instead make the class a singleton, but that's nothing but window dressing. And hell the asp.net core people agree because they use the class in **exactly the same way**. The downvote demonstrates the problem with complex questions - people don't take their time to understand the issue or simply don't have the experience to understand what's wrong in the first place..

Comment: The behavior you are seeing is an unfortunate quirk in the way that ASP.NET Core works (Web API has this same behavior). Disposing is done at the end of the request and for some reason the asynchronous context is already cleared before that point.

Comment: @Steven Yeah was afraid of that. No workaround that springs to your mind I take it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only ways around this is to flow state through the object graph instead of using Ambient state. In other words, make TestRepo scoped, and store value in a private field.

Comment: That works easily in the given trivial example but not d so easy in the actual example I'm afraid. But yeah it's going to be something along those lines.

Comment: Another option is move the operation that uses that value to an earlier stage in thw request. For instance, you can define middleware, wrapping a request, that invokes that operation at the end. At that stage, theasync context will still exist.

Comment: @Steven Oh that's a great idea. Care to make it an answer so I can accept it and throw in a few extra bounty points in 2 days?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is an unfortunate quirk in the way that ASP.NET Core works. It's unclear to me why Microsoft choose this behavior, but it seems copied from the way Web API worked, which has the exact behavior. Disposing is obviously done at the end of the request, but for some reason the asynchronous context is already cleared before that point, making it impossible to run the complete request in a single asynchronous context.

You've basically got two options:

1. Instead of using ambient state to share state, flow state through the object graph instead of using ambient state. In other words, make `TestRepo` Scoped, and store `value` in a private field.
2. Move the operation that uses that value to an earlier stage in the request. For instance, you can define some middleware that wraps a request and invokes that operation at the end. At that stage, the asynchronous context will still exist.

Some DI containers actually apply this second technique. Simple Injector, for instance, uses scoping that is based on ambient state, using `AsyncLocal<T>` under the covers. When integrated in ASP.NET Core, it will wrap the request in a piece of middleware that applies this scope. This means that any Scoped component, resolved from Simple Injector, will be disposed before the ASP.NET Core pipeline disposes its services, and this happens while the asynchronous context is still available.

Comment: Hi Stephen, really helpful answer. I have a short follow-up question. What does the default Asp Net Core DI use under the covers to apply and retrieve scoped context?